# unable to locate element in "popup"

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome

I tried to locate the element by xpath in the webpage, in inspect mode I was able to locate the element:

[Element Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqJgE.png)

but when I execute my program, I am unable to locate the element.

[The popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGLrg.png)

I tried the next code to identify the element but it does not work

```
WebElement ele =(WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementByXpath(//*[contains(text(),'Add an option)')");
```

This is the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected token '}'
```

Comment: Syntax error from what it seems.

Comment: What does the `text(),'Add an option)' mean the ' outside of the ) ?` It makes more sense with `text(),'Add an option')")` You search for `Add an option` not for `Add an option)`